# How to check if object is present in array of objects in hurl.dev

Tags: arrays, json, testing

I am using https://hurl.dev/ for testing, and I have an endpoint that returns an array of objects.

Now I want to assert that this array of object contains a particular array.

How do I do this?

I have tried

```
jsonpath "$" includes '{"id":"123"}'
```

got the error

```
 69 | jsonpath "$" includes '{"id":"123"}'
    |                       ^ invalid predicate value
```

tried

```
jsonpath "$" includes "{\"id\":\"123\"}"
```

Got the error

```
 69 | jsonpath "$" includes "{\"id\":\"123\"}"
    |   actual:   [object]
    |   expected: includes string <{"id":"123"}>
    |
```

This seems to be closer to getting it, but looks like there is a mismatch in types? Also how do I avoid having to manually escape the json string myself.

To try and get the type correct and also not to manually escape the json, I tried

````
jsonpath "$" includes json```{"id":"123"}```
````

but got the error

````
 69 | jsonpath "$" includes json```{"id":"123"}```
    |                       ^ invalid predicate value
````

So question is, if I have an endpoint that returns an array of objects, how do I assert that the response contains/includes a particular object?